# Forcing statement after && to execute when statement before the && is false

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

I have set up form validation using a validate function that runs for a single field, changing its formatting and returning a Boolean. Then to validate the form I have

```
var isValid = validate(field1) && validate(field2) ... ;
```

I would like each invalid field to be highlighted but using this approach the validation stops as soon as an invalid field is reached (due to the way `&&` works).

Obviously I could evaluate validate for each field as a separate statement and then combine the results afterwards, but is there some way I can force the &&'s to not stop after a false result, or some other way of keeping the code to one concise line?

Comment: var isValid = validate(field1) & validate(field2) ... ; Single & should do it

Comment: @HMR: Why don't you post this as an answer ? Comments are for clarifications...

Comment: @Zapshu this particular solution might not work if any ot the validate functions return strings. It's not a 100% proof way to do it as & is entirely not the same as && but works well when values of 0 and 1 or true and false are returned.

Comment: @HMR I considered this (likewise using `*` works) but don't like using `&` as it looks like an accidental typo. However, it is a valid (ahem) answer as the question specifies that the validation function returns a boolean

Answer (score 5):

You can break it out more logically (and readable);

```
var isValid = validate(field1);
    isValid = validate(field2) && isValid;
    isValid = validate(fieldN) && isValid;
```

You could use `&` as HMC suggested using !! to get a bool `!!(a & b & c)`

Or even `var isValid = true == validate(field1) == validate(field2) == validate(fieldN);`

Comment: The first option is the kind of thing I want to avoid doing (I disagree that the multiline version is more readable - using `&&`'s on one line makes it read almost like a sentence), but your `==` method is pretty clever.

Comment: I found another way with ES6 methods: `fields.map(validate).every(val => val)`. Creates an array containing the result of every validation and checks if all of them are true (i.e. valid).